# Java - Migrate Database using JPA

Tags: java, database-migration

I'm brand new to Java Development (comercially) and I just wanted to know if there's an equivalent to EntityFramework in Java.

Something that can update my database quickly.

For some of you that have already worked with .NET, you know that I can add a model, embed it into my dbcontext class and then just run the command: "add-migration [the name of my migration]" and the database will be updated/migrated immediately all of this thanks to EntityFramework.

Is there an equivalent of that in Java? I know there's Flyway but as far as I read, you have to actually write the SQL statement in a file and then Flyway will read it and update the database.

Is there something that can read my entities/models in code (with the JPA annotations) and update the database?

Thanks in advance for your replies. :)